# Inno Setup - AfterInstall action executed multiple times

Tags: inno-setup

I have the following piece of code to run in my script:

```pascal
procedure AddRulesToFirewall();
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  Exec('netsh.exe','advfirewall firewall add rule name="MyApplication" dir=in program="{app}\MyApplication.exe" security=notrequired action=allow protocol=tcp','',SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
end;
```

And I have the following `AfterInstall` action:

```
Source:{#OutputBinaries}\Company*.dll; DestDir: {app}; Components: binaries; AfterInstall: AddRulesToFirewall()
```

However the `AfterInstall` action gets executed many times, therefore I am assuming that it runs the `AfterInstall` action for each binary grouped under this command.

My question is, how should I change this so that the `AddRulesToFirewall` code is only run once after the binaries are installed?

I realise that I could list all the binaries individually in the files section and have the `AfterInstall` only on the last binary, but as there are a lot of binaries I would rather not use this approach.

Comment: The function is called afer each Company*.dll file - you call Wildcard. In such case it is better to add Single File entry with `AfterInstall` flag and the best is to use `CurStepChanged` with `ssPostInstall` as Martin suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Why do you use the `AfterInstall` parameter? How does the firewall rule relate to the DLL files?*

Use the [`CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged) instead:

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    AddRulesToFirewall;
  end;
end;
```

---

Though, if you really need to use the `AfterInstall` for some reason, you can use `CurrentFileName` magic variable, if you know the last file matching the wildcard.

```pascal
procedure AddRulesToFirewall();
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if ExtractFileName(CurrentFileName) = 'CompanyLast.dll' then
  begin
    Exec(
      'netsh.exe',
      'advfirewall firewall add rule name="MyApplication" dir=in ' +
        'program="{app}\MyApplication.exe" security=notrequired action=allow protocol=tcp',
      '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
  end;
end;
```

Though this may be unreliable.

---

Another option is, if the wildcard entry is not the last one, to use the `BeforeInstall` parameter of the next entry.

```
Source: Company*.dll; DestDir: {app}
Source: AnotherFile.dat; DestDir: {app}; BeforeInstall: AddRulesToFirewall()
```